# How can I execute command that has three and/or optional answers in sequence?

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

I have command to execute: `"sudo ssh -L 80:localhost:80 -f -N root@10.19.34.11"` There are three options that in some case I get them and some not:

password for jenkins user:

```
"[sudo] password for jenkins:"
```

answer is "yes or no" to the following:

```
" The authenticity of host '10.19.34.11 (10.19.34.11)' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:96RyrUn7+VMF78YamjgCYYDwD0bzYDaMwHP4YFuQF4Q. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes Warning: Permanently added '10.19.34.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. ############################################################################ WARNING: This system is for the use of authorized clients only. Individuals using the computer network system without authorization, or in excess of their authorization, are subject to having all their activity on this computer network system monitored and recorded by the system personnel. To protect the computer network system from unauthorized use and to ensure the computer network systems is functioning properly, system administrators monitor this system. Anyone using this computer network system expressly consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible conduct of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the evidence of such activity to law enforcement officers. ############################################################################ "
```

password for the remote machine:

```
"Password:"
```

In some cases I need to write just the first, second and third. Some cases: first and third. Some other cases just third.

Can you suggest command line or shell script for dealing with different optional input/output like here?

Comment: Although you can do this kind of thing using the `expect` program, it might be better to avoid the need by (1) configuring your local `sudoers` to avoid the first password prompt (2) passing a less restrictive SSH `StrictHostKeyChecking` setting; then (3) instituting public key authentication to the remote host.

Comment: Middle one you'll only get if the key fingerprint associated with that host IP changes.

Comment: in expect what do I need to test if I want tocatch unique identification of each question. is it enough to make: expect  "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"?

Comment: I created the following: #!/usr/bin/expect

set asms_ip [lindex $argv 0]
set pass_word algosec

spawn sudo ssh -L 80:localhost:80 -f -N root@$asms_ip

expect "password for jenkins"
send -- "$pass_word\r"
expect  "yes/no"
send -- "yes\r"
expect  "Password:"
send -- "$pass_word\r"
expect eof

Comment: @Y.K. if you have found a solution that works for you, please post it as an answer